# EoF / Ctrl+D command in Bash + Python

Tags: python, linux, bash

I'm trying to make some functions in python so that I can connect to a linux terminal and do stuff (like in this case, create a file). The code I have, works partially. The only thing that doesn't work is if you want to do something after you have entered the code. Like for instance you create the file and then want to navigate somewhere else (cd /tmp) for instance. Instead of doing the next command, it will just add to the file created.

```
    def create_file(self, name, contents, location):
        try:
            log.info("Creating a file...")
            self.device.execute("mkdir -p {}".format(location))
            self.cd_path(location)
            self.device.sendline("cat > {}".format(name))
            self.device.sendline("{}".format(contents))
            self.device.sendline("EOF")  # send the CTRL + D command to save and exit I tried here with ^D as well
        except:
            log.info("Failed to create the file!")
```

The contents of the file is:

```
cat test.txt
#!/bin/bash
echo "Fail Method Requested"
exit 1
EOF
ls -d /tmp/asdasd
```

The order of commands executed is:

```
execute.create_file(test.txt, the_message, the_location)
execute.check_path("/tmp/adsasd") #this function just checks with ls -d if the directory exists.
```

I have tried with sendline the following combinations: 
`^D, EOF, <<EOF`

I don't really understand how I could make this happen. I just want to create a file with a specific message. (When researching on how to do this with VI I got the same problem, but there the command I needed was the one for ESC)

If anyone could help with some input that would be great!!

Edit: As Rob mentioned below, sending the character "\x04" actually works. For anyone else having this issue, you can also consult this chart for other combinations if needed:
http://donsnotes.com/tech/charsets/ascii.html

Comment: Wouldn't `sendline` send the actual text to the document, so you need `execute` for sending the EOF. At least that's how I interpreted this, I can't understand much of what your doing.

Comment: BTW have you considered [Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansiblae)?

Comment: What is `self.device`?

Comment: FYI, your code is prone to shell injection attacks unless you use `shlex.quote()` or `pipes.quote()` (depending on your interpreter version) before substituting your variables. Think about what happens if `location` contains `$(rm -rf $HOME)`.

Comment: ...as another aside: bare exception handlers are really bad news -- you might only *expect* an IOError, but if that's the only thing you expect, it's the only thing you should catch -- otherwise, if you somehow get an unexpected exception type, it'll still emit the same "Failed to create the file!" log message and you won't have any way of knowing that something different took place.

Comment: @Robᵩ device is the terminal where I am writing to. It contains the data (imported from a YAML file) on how to connect to a device through ssh.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good point! Thank you. Luckily, this code should theoretically used only be QAs and they shouldn't (not saying they won't :P ) try something like this. 
For the 2nd part of your comment: I will fix that. Thank you again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably need to send the EOF character, which is typically CONTROL-D, not the three characters `E`, `O`, and `F`.

```
        self.device.sendline("\x04")
```

Comment: To be perfectly accurate, that isn't an end of file character.  There _is_ no such thing as an end of file character - it's a state, not a value.  The terminal just interprets ctrl-D to mean end of file.  It's actually the EOT character.  Still, given the question, I think this is a better answer than mine.

Comment: It's the terminal that "closes" the current file in response to an input of Control-D, not `bash`.

Answer (score 2):

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection#here_documents

Here docs allow you to use any file input termination string you like to represent end of file ( such as the literal EOF you're attempting to use now). Quoting that string tells the shell not to interpret expansions inside the heredoc content, ensuring that said content is treated as literal.

Using `pipes.quote()` here ensures that filenames with literal quotes, `$`s, spaces, or other surprising characters won't break your script. (Of course, you'll need to `import pipes`; on Python 3, by contrast, this has moved to `shlex.quote()`).

```
self.device.sendline("cat > {} <<'EOF'".format(pipes.quote(name)))
```

Then you can write the EOF as is, having told bash to interpret it as the end of file input.

Comment: Excellent point! Perhaps you could demonstrate, using OP's `.sendline()` calls, how to use a here document.